# Open Activity A and load a specific fragment of Activity A FROM Activity B

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I have Activity A which loads fragments based on menu selects. If I make an intent from Activity B to Activity A, the default specified Activity A fragment will load. What I want to achieve is to load another fragment from Activity A instead of the default one. I hope this makes at least a bit of sense. What I tried to do is this -->

In Activity B I have -->

```
btnlinkToForum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ReaderActivity.class);

    i.putExtra("fragmentNumber", 1);
    startActivity(i);
}

});
```

And I try based on the putExtra data to load the specific fragment in Activity A like that --> I put this code into the onCreate method

```
if (getIntent().getIntExtra("fragmentNumber", 0) == 1) {
    FragmentManager fm = ReaderActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    FragmentForum fragment = new FragmentForum();

        if (fragment != null) {
            // Replace current fragment by this new one
            ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment);
            ft.commit();

            // Set title 
            tvTitle.setText("Forum");
        }
}
```

This however loads the default fragment instead ... Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you put a log there and see if `getIntent().getIntExtra("fragmentNumber", 0)` always return 0?

Comment: Which is your default fragment  ? Have tried debugging your code and checked whether it goes inside if loop or not ? \

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. I just logged it and it seems that getIntent().getIntExtra("fragmentNumber", 0)  always returns 0 and it never goes inside the if statement ...

Comment: I am 10)% stuck here ... Whatever I do I don't seem to pass a value via putExtra()  and get it retrieved via another activity using getExtra() ... Can anyone give an example on how this can be done ... Whenever I try to get the value using for example getIntent().getStringExtra("whatever"); I get a null value ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone give an example on how this can be done ... Whenever I try
>   to get the value using for example
>   getIntent().getStringExtra("whatever"); I get a null value ... –

Definitely you shall get values from one activity to another for example:

Activity_A.java

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
i.putStringExtra("key", value);
startActivity(i);
```

Activity_B.java

```
onCreate()
{

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String var = i.getStringExtra("key");
    ..
}
```

P.S: If you would like to pass an object

```
i.putSerializable("object", object);
```

and

```
(Class) i.getSerializable("object");
```

Comment: This works ;) My issue was that I mixed the button ids that initialized the intent so basically I though I was pressing the right button because the name of the button was correct but I was referencing the wrong button id so that is why I was always getting a null value! This being said below is the code that works for me! In activity B:

Comment: Glad to hear this..   :-)

Comment: Intent does not have `putStringExtra(key, value)` method. It should be just `putExtra(key, value)`. eg. intent.putExtra("key", "somevalue");

Answer (score 8):

This works ;) My issue was that I mixed the button ids that initialized the intent so basically I though I was pressing the right button because the name of the button was correct but I was referencing the wrong button id so that is why I was always getting a null value! This being said below is the code that works for me! In activity B:

```
btnToForum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(RssListActivity.this,
                        ReaderActivity.class);
                //pass data to an intent to load a specific fragment of reader activity
                String fragmnet = "forum";
                i.putExtra("fragment", fragmnet); 
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

In Activity A:

```
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String fragmentName = i.getStringExtra("fragment");
        String forum = "forum";
        Log.e("Test1", "Test1" + fragmentName);
        if (fragmentName != null && fragmentName.equals(forum)) {

Do some magic here ;)
}
```